# which is wrong? 1. "What is your suggest?" 2. "What is your suggestion?"

Tags: verbs, nouns

which is wrong?
1. "What is your suggest?" 
2. "What is your suggestion?"

Comment: The first one is the wrong one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example 'What is your suggest?' is wrong. To rephrase that example to be correct would be 'What do you suggest?'. To reply, one would say 'I suggest ...'.

The definitions just for clarity to how to use *suggest* and *suggestion*:

> **Suggest**
>  verb (used with object)
>   1. to mention or introduce (an idea, proposition, plan, etc.) for consideration or possible action:
>   *The architect suggested that the building be restored.*
>   2. to propose (a person or thing) as suitable or possible for some purpose:
>   *We suggested him for president.*
>   3. (of things) to prompt the consideration, making, doing, etc., of:
>   *The glove suggests that she was at the scene of the crime.*
>   4. to bring before a person's mind indirectly or without plain expression:
>   *I didn't tell him to leave, I only suggested it.*
>   5. to call (something) up in the mind through association or natural connection of ideas:
>   *The music suggests a still night.*
>
> **Suggestion**
>   noun
>   1. the act of suggesting.
>   2. the state of being suggested.
>   3. something suggested, as a piece of advice:
>   *We made the suggestion that she resign.*
>   4. a slight trace:
>   *He speaks with a suggestion of a foreign accent.*
>   5. the calling up in the mind of one idea by another by virtue of some association or of some natural connection between the ideas.
>   6. the idea thus called up.
>   7. Psychology.
>   a. the process of inducing a thought, sensation, or action in a receptive person without using persuasion and without giving rise to reflection in the recipient.
>   b. the thought, sensation, or action induced in this way.

(dictionary.reference.com)

Answer (score 1):

'What do you suggest?' and 'What is your suggestion?' are the correct formations.

'What is your suggest?' is incorrect as **suggest** is a verb and cannot be used a noun.

Comment: That's perfectly fine :)

Answer (score 0):

SUGGEST, a verb has the noun form SUGGESTION.Now,shape it in sentences of your own.
¶ What do you suggest? (as verb)
¶¶ What is your suggestion? (as noun)